# Aggrid pivot group selection doesn't select child rows

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

So in Aggrid, I create pivot by project and whenever I click on checkbox at project name, it doesn't select anything. I have checked that via `gridApi.getSelectedRows()` and the array of selected rows is empty `[]` for the case displayed on screenshot below.

How to configure group selection so it selects all items of the group?

[image: not grouped]

Answer (score 0):

Configuration has been missing `groupSelectsChildren: true`, however, this isn't mentioned in Pivot section in aggrid